# Typescript restrict type with no properties from accepting strings or arrays

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to restrict `param` not to accept strings, arrays etc.?

```
interface foo {
    a?: number;
    b?: string;
}

function baz(param: foo) {
}

baz("hello");
```

Comment: Why do you care? If it fits your interface, why do you mind whether it's a string or an object?

Comment: We had a bug where we were passing the object's property instead of the object, and typescript compiled fine.

Comment: That is a valid concern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this to make `baz` accept at least an object:

```
interface foo {
    a?: number;
    b?: string;
}

interface notAnArray {
    forEach?: void
}

type fooType = foo & object & notAnArray;

function baz(param: fooType) {
}

baz("hello"); // Throws error
baz([]); // Throws error
```

`fooType` here is an [Intersection Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html).

Comment: Isn't that cheating a bit? You are forcing that the parameter has to be an object.

Comment: @MuratK.: Isn't that what the OP wants? But I would lean toward not making it a type, just `function baz(param: foo & object)`

Comment: Worth noting that the `object` type is very new, you'll need TypeScript 2.2 to use it.

Comment: Nice one, is there a type that allows objects apart from array?

Comment: @user3233089 yes, for some definition of array: `interface NotAnArray { forEach?: void }`

Comment: @artem Nice! Updated the answer.